# Multiple URL key-value pair parameters that are optional in Django

Tags: python, django, url, url-rewriting

I'm looking for a way to have multiple optional URL parameters (key-value pairs) in a Django project.

Ideally I need something capable of processing an infinite number of key-value pairs. In the format shown below.

`http://example.com/example/key1/value1/`

`http://example.com/example/key1/value1/key2/value2/`

`http://example.com/example/key1/value1/key2/value2/key3/value3/`

The use case for this sort of URL structure is for different filters that may or may not be applied to a list of objects, traditionally I would use query strings, but I'm under the impression that query strings are not as good for SEO.

I'm not too sure of two things:

1. How to write the URL rule
2. How to interpret the key-value parameters in the view

Any help/pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think perhaps you're misunderstanding the representation of the sample URLs you've provided, which are hierarchies - not key/value pairs. If you need key/value pairs, just use querystring parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this url to `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^example/(.*)', 'app.views.key_values_view'),
```

And then get a dict of key/value pairs:

```
def key_values_view(request, path):

    bits = path.split('/')
    it = iter(bits)
    data = dict(zip(it, it))

    key1 = data.get('key1')
    key2 = data.get('key2')
    key3 = data.get('key3')

    ...
```

Comment: Hey catavaran, thanks for the answer, although I'm getting the following error: `'list' object has no attribute 'get'` any ideas?